# SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

When I run the Node.js server it's OK. But when I run the `person GET` route it returns an empty JSON array and logs:

> SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file.

Why can't the database file be opened? The database files:

/api/database/databse.db
/api/database/connection.js

```js
//This is the connection.js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

exports.open = (database) => {
    database = new sqlite3.Database(database, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err.message);
        }
    });

    return database;
}

exports.close = (database) => {
    database.close((err) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
    });
}
```

/api/model/UserModel.js

```js
const database = require('../database/connection');

class Person {
    constructor (id, firstName, lastName, birthdate, height, weight) {
        this.id = id || 0;
        this.firstName = firstName || "none";
        this.lastName = lastName || "none";
        this.height = height || 0;
        this.weight = weight || 0;
        this.birthdate = birthdate ? new Date(birthdate) : "none";
    }

    // [...] getter functions that calculates and concatenates datas
}

// [...] annother databse function, not used yet (register function)

function getEveryone () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        let everyone = [];

        const sql = "SELECT * FROM person;";
        const db = database.open('./database/database.db');
        
        db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(JSON.stringify({message : `Erro: ${err.message}`}));
            }

            rows.forEach(row => {
                const id = row.id;
                const firstName = row.firstName;
                const lastName = row.lastName;
                const height = row.height;
                const weight = row.weight;
                const birthdate = row.birthdate;
                everyone.push(new Person(id, firstName, lastName, height, weight, birthdate));
            });
        });

        database.close(db);
        resolve(everyone);
    });
}

module.exports = {
    Person,
    getEveryone,
    register
}
```

/api/controller/PersonController.js

```js
const Person = require('../model/PersonModel');

async function getEveryone (req, res) {
    try {
        const everyone = await Person.getEveryone();
        console.log(`Everyone on Controller: ${everyone}`);
        
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify({everyone}));
    } catch (error) {
        res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify({"startStats" : `Reporte o ocorrido! Ocorreu o seguinte erro: ${error}`}));
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getEveryone
}
```

/api/server.js

```js
const http = require('http');
const { getEveryone } = require('./controller/PersonController');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    const url = req.url;

    if (req.method == 'GET') {
        switch (url) {
            case "/api/person":
                getEveryone(req, res);
                break;
        }
    } else if (req.method == 'POST') {
        switch (url) {
            case "/api/person":
                res.writeHead(201, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                res.end(JSON.stringify({"startStats" : "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!"}));
                break;
        }
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify({"startStats" : "Rota não encontrada!"}));
    }
});

server.listen(port, hostname, ()=>{
    console.log(`Servidor rodando em http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

On this part of the API I want to get all the table person's lines. I tried to change the database path in PersonModel.js to `'../database/database.db'` and `'./../database/database.db'` but got the same error. I want to open the database file and then see if the API is querying right.

Comment: Try using the absolute path to the database file instead of a relative path.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! It solved the issue. But why do I need to use the absolute path in this case nor the relative path? I have already done annother API like this and I used relative path normally.

Comment: The working directory is not what you think it is, so the relative path wasn't correct.

Comment: @Barmar ok. I'll search for the correct directory, so! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the relative path, using `dirname`.

On the top of `PersonModel.js` code, I created the following variable:

```js
const databaseDirectory = __dirname + '/../database/database.db';
```

How `./../database/database.db` or `../database/database.db` wasn't working, I created a variable that receives its code file's directory then, from it, complete the directory with the relative path to the database.

So to pass the database's file path, I use this variable.